# Failed Let's Encrypt standalone authorization procedure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, lets-encrypt

First, thanks to all who may or may not try to help me.
My Problem: I'm trying to create an ssl certificate with Let's Encrypt. Already installed everything mentioned in the documentation. I decided to use certbot / since it seemed to be the easiest way for me to fulfill my needs.

We have freed both ports 80 and 443 and every request that comes to one of these ports are redirected to my Ubuntu 18.04 machine's internal IP address.

There are no configurations on this machine, so nothing listens on port 80 or 443, as you can see on my netstat command:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      895/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1211/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1211/sshd
```

After creating the certificate I'll run a spring boot application, which should use the certificate.

As far as I understood from the documentation, it isn't required to have running applications listening on these ports. It ought be possible to create the certificate by using the standalone parameter. So I guess certbot creates a small application listening to one of these ports on it's own to verify that I'm the one, who I claim to be. Right?

`placeholder.example.com` is as you will assume a placeholder. I think it's obvious why I'm not publishing my domainname, when having port 80 & 443 opened.

```
root@urlaub:/# certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http -d placeholder.example.com

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for placeholder.example.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. placeholder.example.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching http://placeholder.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/jCJ4waxV0aYPxjqDI3OcBXXPReNSrse1kd6piK9Dwdo: Connection refused

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: placeholder.example.com
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Fetching
   http://placeholder.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/jCJ4waxV0aYPxjqDI3OcBXXPReNSrse1kd6piK9Dwdo:
   Connection refused

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

**EDIT:** I've had tried this a lot of times, without success. Now there are 13 .pem files in /etc/letsencrypt/keys
Can I convert them to .p12 file to use it in an spring boot application?

Comment: "placeholder.mydomain.com is as you will assume a placeholder." then use `placeholder.example.com`, as `mydomain.com` is certainly not a placeholder, it exists online.

Comment: Edited. Don't understand what was odd to use placeholder.mydomain.com though.

Comment: Simple: do you think `mydomain.com` exist today on Internet and is used actively by someone? If no, please double check. If yes, is this your domain? If it isn't, imagine what is happening for the true owner. For all details, please have a read at RFC 2606: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt    For another example: the `.MAIL`  TLD will never exist for real just because it has been (ab)used by numerous documentations which renders it now impossible to use without breaking many people configurations.

Comment: "I think it's obvious why I'm not publishing my domainname"  this is security by obscurity (which does not work) : besides making troubleshooting more complicated for anyone, do you know that the list of domain names, specifically `.COM` ones, is public data, so anyone can at some point find yours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the redirection to my server machine. So the above used command works properly and I was able to create a certificate. If anyone wants to use it: go for it.

My intent was to use it in a spring boot application and needed a pkcs12 file. I was able to convert the .pem files created by certbot to a .p12 file by using following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out keystore.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile chain.pem -caname tomcat
```

In your application.properties you've to put following:

```
server.port: PORTNUMBER
server.ssl.key-store:/etc/letsencrypt/live/<YOURDOMAIN>/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: <PASSWORD YOU WERE PROMPTED WHEN CREATING THE CERTIFICATE>
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

Answer (score 0):

With Let's Encrypt if you use HTTP validation, you will need a server serving requests on port 80 (HTTP) for `placeholder.mydomain.com` so that the Let's Encrypt server can download the file `.well-known/acme-challenge/jCJ4waxV0aYPxjqDI3OcBXXPReNSrse1kd6piK9Dwdo`. This is how Let's Encrypt validates that you have control over the domain. Note: That filename is generated dynamically and will be different each time you attempt validation.

Another option that I use is to use DNS validation and then create the special record in my DNS server. You can then create the certificates on your desktop for any service that requires SSL for that domain name.

Comment: Why would I need a server that serves request on port 80? I'm trying to get a certificate using certbot as I'd mentioned in my post. Cerbot will create a small http server by its own for the validation, so why would I need to do that?

Comment: The error messages shows that there is no server running on port 80.

Comment: That's correct. However the standalone parameter tells certbot, that no http server or any application is running on the machine. Certbot starts an small http server and serves on port 80 and creates a file to make it possible for letsencrypt checking on the given domain. If letsencrypt can connect on the machine successfully using the domain and can find the file it signs that I'm the domain owner and I'll get the certificate.

Comment: The error messages shows that there is no server running on port 80.

Comment: Can connection refused be caused if you have a DNS record redirecting http to https:?

Comment: @Michael - DNS does not support HTTP -> HTTPS redirection (any form of port redirection). Some service providers have a feature called URL Redirect, but this is not part of DNS. This feature redirects an entire domain to another domain.

Comment: @JohnHanley This is a non-answer. As the OP mentioned, with `--standalone` certbot should start its own webserver.

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius - My answer is over two years old. Let's Encrypt tools have changed a lot since then. I do not remember if the option you mention was available/reliable back then. If you can post a better answer that represents today's state, please do so.